# Getting Output from the java process

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am building a javaFx application I am running a command using java process builder class.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(runCommand);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
try {
    process.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am trying to get the output from the process I have tried two different ways but I am not able to get it.

```
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));
String line1=null;
while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line1);
}
BufferedReader errorred = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stderr));
while ((line1 = errorred.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line1);
}
```

I tried also this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(runCommand);
//String outputLogs = new VerboseProcess(new ProcessBuilder(""));
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process process = builder.start();
try {
    process.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Could you try the snippet from my answer and check the result on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is somewhere else. Following snippet is based on your posted code

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-version");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
process.waitFor();
int exitValue = process.exitValue();
System.out.println("exitValue = " + exitValue);

InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
String line1 = null;
while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line1);
}
BufferedReader errorred = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
while ((line1 = errorred.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line1);
}
```

and produces the following output on the console

```
exitValue = 0
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

If the command specified in `new ProcessBuilder(command...)` does not exists or is not in the PATH an `IOException` is thrown

```
Cannot run program "...": CreateProcess error=2, The system \
    cannot find the file specified
```

If you don't get any output. Following could be the reason:

- the process has not printed anything to stdout/stderr
- your `runcommand` start the process in a background process, e.g. on Linux/OSX `command &` or on Windows `start command.exe`

Comment: this is giving output for me but if I replace new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-version"); with new ProcessBuilder(runcommand); and run it doesn't give anything. So should I change something in my ProcessBuilder argument to return the output. Even if there is some problem with the command shouldn't it give some error message ??

Comment: @user3649361 I have updated my answer. Add the part with the `exitCode` to see which exit code your started process returns.

Comment: I am not getting any output, it's seems the process is starting in background, how to resolve this ??

Comment: @user3649361 Post the value of `runcommand` For sure private data can be replaced by dummy values, but leave the syntax the same as you are using it.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you , what are you trying to say ??

Comment: @user3649361 To be able to help you with your question `seems the process is starting in background, how to resolve this` it's necessary to know what is the value of your variable `runcommand`.

Comment: actually I am installing a .exe file using this command in what we called silent mode so you can't use this command because you will not be having the asses to the .exe file

Comment: @user3649361 Then it's impossible to give you an advice whats wrong with your command. Have a look add my updated answer. There is now a hint. Maybe this already helps.